# Initializing and Deleting a 2d Array

Tags: c++, arrays

I've looked at a few other threads, but can't seem to figure out how to delete a 2d array.

Here is how I'm initializing the array. `num_items` and `capacity` are predetermined variables:

```
int **P = new int *[num_items]; 
for (x = 0; x <= num_items; x++)
     P[x] = new int[capacity];
```

Here is how I thought I was suppose to delete it, however, it is crashing:

```
for(x = 0; x <= num_items; x++)
    delete [] P[x];
delete [] P;
```

To clarify, I want the array P to hold 1 extra of num_items. So if num_items = 7, than I want the array size to be 8 so that P[7] is valid.

Comment: Unless this is for educational purposes: Never call new/delete yourself, use smart pointers ([`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) and [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr)) instead.

Comment: @user2176127 *never* is a bit too much.  There are cases where you will need to manage memory yourself (which should be done in the context of a class), but they are rare.

Answer (score 5):

Your comment "Don't need to add +1 to num_items" and your implementation of the for loop contradict each other.

Remember that arrays are 0-based, so P has valid indices 0 up to **but not including num_items**. However, in your for loop, x takes on the values 0 up to **and including num_items**.

Thus, the fix is likely

```
for (x = 0; x < num_items; x++)
    /* whatever */
```

All of this being said, can you use `std::vector` instances instead? Then, you don't have to worry about this sort of memory management.

Comment: I'd also suggest looking at http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/multi_array/doc/user.html since using `vector` still means a potentially ragged matrix.

Comment: Sorry that comment was meant for something else and I meant to delete that before posting it

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is your math:

```
int **P = new int *[num_items];
for (x = 0; x <= num_items; x++) // PROBLEM!
     P[x] = new int[capacity];
```

Arrays in C/C++ are 0-based, so when you declare it to have a size `X`, you can access all of the elements from 0 to `X-1`.  Your less-than-or-equal-to comparison will attempt to access element `X`, which is memory outside the bounds of what you have declared, so you get undefined behavior.  What you want is:

```
int **P = new int *[num_items];
for (x = 0; x < num_items; x++)
     P[x] = new int[capacity];
```

And then

```
for(x = 0; x < num_items; x++)
    delete [] P[x];
delete [] P;
```

That said, using `std::vector` would be the better solution.